# SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, migration

I'm newbiу in laravel 9. I just want create simple blog with the tables:users, stories,comments.I have next relationship

```
users->stories(One To Many, hasMany laravel) , 
stories->users(One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To), 
users->comments(One To Many, hasMany laravel) , 
comments->users(One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To),
stories->comments(One To Many, hasMany laravel) , 
comments->stories(One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To).
```

class User

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
    
    use App\Models\Story;
    use App\Models\Comment;
    
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array<int, string>
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'password',
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
         *
         * @var array<int, string>
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password',
            'remember_token',
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be cast.
         *
         * @var array<string, string>
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
        
        public function stories()
        {
          return $this->hasMany(Story::class);
        }
        
        public function comments()
        {
          return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
        }
    }
```

class Story:

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    use App\Model\User;
    use App\Model\Comment;
    
    class Story extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        
         protected $fillable = ['description', 'textStory'];
         
         public function user()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }
        
        public function comments()
        {
          return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
        }
    }
```

class Comment:

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    use App\Models\Story;
    use App\Models\User;
    
    class Comment extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        
         public function storyFunction()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo(Story::class);
        }
         public function userFunction()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }
        
    }
```

Stories migration:

```
<?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    return new class extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('stories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('description');
                $table->text('textStory');
                $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('stories');
        }
    };
```

Comments migration:

```
<?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    return new class extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->text('textComment');
                //$table->foreignId('story_id')->constrained('stories')->onDelete('cascade');
                /*$table->foreign('story_id')
              ->references('id')->on('stories')
              ->onDelete('cascade');*/
                $table->timestamps();
            });
            
            
       Schema::table('comments', function(Blueprint $table) {
           $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
       });
       
       Schema::table('comments', function(Blueprint $table) {
           $table->foreignId('story_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
       });
       
       
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
        }
    };
```

But when i run php artisan migrate or php artisan migrate:refresh i see next error:

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ?z?????С?s??:  ??NВ????N??╡?????╡ "stories
> " ???╡ N?N?NЙ?╡N?NВ??N??╡NВ (SQL: alter table "comments" add constraint "comment
> s_story_id_foreign" foreign key ("story_id") references "stories" ("id") on dele
> te cascade)

But if i delete or comment next strings in comments migration file:

```
Schema::table('comments', function(Blueprint $table) {
       $table->foreignId('story_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
   });
```

Migration run succesfull.

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: check tables name in database.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the table that Laravel finds using the conventions is missing. Specify the table explicitly as an argument to the constrained method like this Schema::table('comments', function(Blueprint $table) {
$table->foreignId('story_id')->constrained('Your_table_name')->onDelete('cascade');
});[Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: i'm doing it Schema::table('comments', function(Blueprint $table) {
       $table->foreignId('story_id')->constrained('stories')->onDelete('cascade');
   });
but the error not disappear

Comment: does table stories in the database?

Comment: Migrate stories before migrating comments

Comment: if i migrate stories before migrate comments, using command:"php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2022_02_21_112912_create_stories_table.php"

Comment: and then migrate comments D:\AngularLaravelBlog\blog>php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2022_02_21_112331_create_comments_table.php
error disappear.But if i use "php artisan migrate" or "php artisan migrate:refresh"   error stay.
if the way resolve error when i use 'php artisan migrate' ?
if i migrate stories and then comments whether all relationships between tables will be preserved ?

Comment: all relationships will be saved. relationships or table relationships are an architectural aspect of your database, not a programming one.  relationships are instructions that are given to the framework to properly interact with and work with the entities in the database, through eloquent models.  the relationships will be exactly what you specified in the models.